When compiling C with gcc, how can I enforce C90 standards but with a few specific C99 features added in?
I'm working on developing an application in C for classic Mac OS, and I'm using a gcc-based toolchain on a modern system to cross-compile. Because that toolchain may have incompatibilities or bugs, I want to keep my C code compatible with C compilers on classic Mac OS, namely Think C or CodeWarrior, so that I can compile using those as a fallback option.
However, these compilers supported a version of C that doesn't fully line up with either the c90 or gnu90 standards. Specifically, they are c90 with the following c99 features: C++ style comments, inline functions, and flexible array members. I'd like to be able to use these features, but make sure I don't use any other C99 features that these old compilers don't support.
So far I can't find a combination of compiler flags that'll allow this specific combination of features while disallowing everything else in c99 and later.
What I've tried so far:

-std=gnu90: this of course allows everything from gnu90, including features of gnu90 that aren't supported by these early mac compilers.

-std=gnu90 -pedantic -pedantic-error: this disallows C++ comments with no obvious switch to allow it.

-std=c90: this disallows both C++ comments and inline functions with no switch I can find to allow them.

-std=gnu90 -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror=variadic-macros: this is the closest I've come, in that it at least disallows declaring variables amid code, but for some reason it still allows variadic macros unless I also use -pedantic. But then it also produces unwanted warnings about C++ style comments and inline functions.


Is there any combination of command line arguments that'll allow for compiling C with these specific features?

Why not just compile with one of these compilers as part of the build process?

Why not simply build with the C99 standard enabled? While some parts of older standard might be marked as obsolete, it very seldom actually removes something. It's very likely that the code will still work in C99 mode (with or without GCC-specific extension). And for the few things that might break, maybe might be worth the time to refactor those parts so they work in C99?

@n.m.couldbeanAI That's much easier said than done, as these old compilers can only run on classic Mac OS and it's non-trivial to get modern build tools to interface with them. Really what I'm trying to do is use a modern editors and tools to build classic mac apps (with retro68 as the toolchain) but I want my code to be able to be compiled on a classic Mac OS just in case I hit an incompatibility with it, as retro68 isn't a 100% compatible toolchain for classic mac development. Hence needing to confirm to an old C standard.

@Someprogrammerdude I need my code to be able to be compiled on classic Mac OS. None of those compilers support C99! Hence my question.

When you say "classic Mac OS", do you mean pre-OSX (e.g. Mac OS 9 or earlier)? In that case I would recommend you instead try to use a modern compiler to cross-compile to the older target. And ask your customer to upgrade to modern system (where "modern" mean anything manufactured during the last 20 years). Supporting such old hardware is only going to cost both you and your customers more in the long run, and it's only going to get worse every year you and your customers push it forward.

Oh and upgrading the hardware and operating systems doesn't mean you have to stop supporting the programs or your systems. It's still possible to support legacy program even on modern systems. I've done such a transition myself, when upgrading both hardware and OS, from Windows XP to Windows 10. Still used the old code, still used the same IDE and compiler (Borland C++ 6.0), just installed it on the new systems without too much problems.

@Someprogrammerdude This question is for a personal project where I want to make a game for classic Mac OS (System 7 specifically) for fun, nostalgia and the challenge. There are no customers! The whole point is to make it for an obsolete system, so being able to compile on that system is a hard requirement. I'm already using a cross-compiling toolchain (retro68) but it's not perfect—and cross compiling for classic Mac is non-trivial!—so I want a fallback option of compiling using the actual classic Mac compilers. Hence needing to enforce compliance with their uncommon version of C.

You might want to include all that in the question itself, it will help explain what you're really doing, and the original and underlying problem you try to solve. And make your question less of an XY problem.

I've updated my question with more of that information

how can I enforce C90 standards but with a few specific C99 features added in? Compile with C99 standard and also additionally write your own linter that checks that specific C99 features are not used and use that linter to check the code.
